# How to write a matrix of quaterions on matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of quaterions numbers I need to write it on matlab; I try with:

```
a=  [[0.7071 0.7071 0 0] ,  [0.7071 0.7071 0 0],   [0.7071 0.7071 0 0] ]
```

but it doesn't work. When I put size(a) the result is 1 12 on the other hand the result must be 1 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you might want to use [cells](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html).

Try:

```
a = {[0.7071 0.7071 0 0] ,  [0.7071 0.7071 0 0],   [0.7071 0.7071 0 0]};
size(a)
ans =

   1   3
```

To use it you must [index](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) it as cells using curly brackets:

```
a{1}
ans =

   0.70710   0.70710   0.00000   0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just appending 3 1x4 matrices in a row it will result 1x12 matrix of course.  `[0.7071 0.7071 0 0 , 0.7071 0.7071 0 0, 0.7071 0.7071 0 0]` this and  `[[0.7071 0.7071 0 0] , [0.7071 0.7071 0 0], [0.7071 0.7071 0 0] ]` this are same. Have a look at [this basic tutorial](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html)